# Not able to host the python application in docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to host the sample application in docker. But not able to host. run the application.
I believe it should host in http://127.0.0.1:8001 I have exposed the port 8001

docker file

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

EXPOSE 8001

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8001", "pythonPath.to.wsgi"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  vscodedjangodocker:
    image: vscodedjangodocker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
```

Comment: Did you check the docker container logs? Also, try to hit "http://localhost:8001" once.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal seems some exception in workerprocess

Comment: Adding the output from docker-compose would be very helpful, that workerprocess exception is potentially crashing the container. Telling us what the current behavior is is necessary.